# Stop button wrapping to newline

Tags: html, asp.net, css

In design mode in VS the following code has all the buttons on a single row

[image]

HTML:

```
<!-- top -->
<div id="top">
    <Label id="validCredentialsMessage" class="float-right" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="" Visible="true"></Label>
    <a href="home.aspx" id="logo" class="float-left"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
    <div id="top-menu" class="float-right">
        <ul class="main">
            <li><a id="A1" href="home.aspx"  runat="server" class="current"><span>Home</span></a> </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span>Members</span></a>
                <ul class="sub curved">
                    <li><a href="ratings.aspx">Analysis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="results.aspx">Results</a></li>
                    <li><a href="performance.aspx">Performance</a></li>                           
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="blog.aspx"><span>Blog</span></a> </li>
            <li><a href="contact.aspx"><span>Contact</span></a> </li>
            <li><a href="Default.aspx"><span>Account</span></a> </li>
            <li><a id="iLogOut"  runat="server" onserverclick ="LogOut_Click"><span>LogOut</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- //top -->
```

CSS:

```css
/* top menu */
#top-menu {padding:19px 0 0 0;width:560px;}
#top-menu ul {list-style:none;padding:0;margin:0;}
#top-menu .main li, #top-menu .main li a, #top-menu .main li a span {display:block;float:left;cursor:pointer;}
#top-menu .main li a, #top-menu .main li a span {background:url(../images/top-menu-a.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;}
#top-menu .main li {position:relative;padding-bottom:4px;}
#top-menu.float-left .main li {padding-right:10px;}
#top-menu.float-right .main li {padding-left:10px;}
#top-menu .main li a {background-position:top left;padding:0 0 0 20px;color:#656565;}
#top-menu .main li a span {background-position:top right;height:25px;line-height:25px;text-align:center;padding:0 20px 0 0;font-family:LucidaGrandeBold, Arial, sans-serif;}
#top-menu .main li a:hover {background-position:bottom left;}
#top-menu .main li a:hover span, #top-menu .main li a.current span {background-position:bottom right;}
#top-menu .main li a:hover, #top-menu .main li a.current {color:#5790dc;background-position:bottom left;}
#top-menu .main .current-dynamic > a {color:#5790dc;background-position:bottom left;}
#top-menu .main .current-dynamic > a span {background-position:bottom right;}
#top-menu .sub {background:url(../images/top-menu-sub.jpg) repeat-x #fafafa;position:absolute;top:27px;left:10px;padding:15px 20px 10px 20px;border:1px solid #e0e0e0;min-width:110px;display:none;z-index:50;}
#top-menu.float-left .sub {left:0;}
#top-menu .sub li, #top-menu .sub li a, #top-mnu .sub li a span {display:block;float:none;background:none;padding:0;}
#top-menu.float-left .sub li, #top-menu.float-right .sub li {line-height:25px;padding:2px 0;}
#top-menu .sub li a {font-family:LucidaGrandeRegular, Arial, sans-serif;}
/* -- */
```

However, when running live the last button wraps even though there's enough room.

[image]

It's frustrating as the design view looks correct and only changes live which makes it difficult to track down which settings have an effect. Please can anybody advise a simple way to stop these buttons wrapping onto a new row?

Comment: Do you have a reset on your CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line of your css, `#top-menu` has a property `width: 560px;` which causes the buttons to wrap.

Around `605px` seems to be the minimum setting here as it is the space needed by the buttons.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwNFf/1/).

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Frustrating as I'm sure I tried that :)